# can do this with JPA / Hibernate criteriabuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteriabuilder

I am working with oracle and using JPA with Hibernate, can we do this with criteriabuilder?

```sql
SELECT col1,col2,col3
FROM table(schema.fn_name(param1,param2,param3))
ORDER BY col1,col2;
```

the query can display other additional field (xyz) as well, although there is no such column. I can do this with callable statement

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible yet, but is being discussed here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/discussions/5898
So if you want to be notified about progress on this topic, then you can watch that GitHub discussion.